# react-native-onesignal Could not get unknown property 'android' for root project 'weather' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, react-native

I have **included react-native-onesignal**  in my project. When running `react-native run-android` I'm getting this error.

Here is my `build.gradle` file, looks like:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
    }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.0, 0.99.99]'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

And this is my `app/build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation (project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration doc is quite misleading for onesignal.

The line that they are saying to add in project root **build.gradle** should be added in the **app/build.gradle** file. Thus I solved my problem.

For more check out the example app of onesignal. [example app](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/tree/master/examples/RNOneSignal/android)